# Are shirts allowed in pro boxing?

Tags: boxing, uniform

Are male pro boxers allowed to wear shirts or must they fight topless?

I know that they usually don't wear shirts, but are shirts actually prohibited by the WBA, WBC, WBO, or IBF?

Answer (score 5):

The [Association of Boxing Commissions rules](https://apbcboxing.com/?page_id=28) prohibits shirts for their boxers.

> 1.17    Contestants may wear only boots and shorts approved by the Inspector and the Referee.  Male Boxers must be stripped to the waist. Female Boxers will wear above the waist a singlet under which such protective cover as sports bra with breast protector inserts or a one piece breast protector must be worn.

[The WBA do not seem to have any rules on apparel](https://www.wbaboxing.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/World-Boxing-Association-Rules.pdf) (although they do address bandaging and protective cups). [Nothing from WBC](https://wbcboxing.com/en/descarga/rule-1/?wpdmdl=3416&refresh=6398dc7ad4c3a1670962298) or [WBO](https://wboboxing.com/wp-content/pdf/wbo-regulations.pdf). I don't see anything in the [IBF](https://www.ibf-usba-boxing.com/) rules about shirts, although their [Bout Rules](https://www.ibfusbaregistration.com/ibfusba_02APR2014/images/pdfs/BoutRules.pdf) do require the color of the fighter's trunks to be noted.

In general, male boxers do not wear shirts because they provide a way to be grabbed, they can reduce freedom of movement, and they decrease heat dissipation.

Comment: Although most male boxers likely prefer to box shirtless for the reasons you mention, I wonder why the APBC actually made a rule about it.  I have a hunch it was to increase attendance at bouts, but that's purely speculation.